# Absolute positioned content overflowing sticky footer

Tags: html, css, layout, css-position

In my current layout I have the entire page set at 100% and the footer is positioned so that it stays at the bottom of the page no matter what. However, I have added a few circles in CSS to the page for my design, but when I try to absolute position them at the bottom, they seem to overflow the footer itself and I cannot figure out how to fix this issue.

Here is a working example: http://codepen.io/keenanpayne/pen/JYOKep

Here is what's currently happening:

[image: Current Result]

Here is what I want to happen:

[image: Intended Result]

**HTML:**

```
<div class="demo">
  <div id="content">
    <h1>Heading</h1>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>

    <p>At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="footer">
  <p>This is a footer</p>
</div>

<div class="circle--purple"></div>
<div class="circle--gold"></div>
<div class="circle--teal"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
/**
 * Demo Styles
 */

html {
  height: 150%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after { box-sizing: inherit; }

body { 
  background: #f2f2f2;
  position: relative;
  /* NOTE: Disabing "position: relative" allows the
           circles to stay at the bottom of the window, 
           but not the bottom of the viewport. 
  */
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
}


/**
 * Footer Styles
 */

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
}


/**
 * Circle Styles
 */
.circle--gold,
.circle--purple,
.circle--teal {
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 150ms
}

.circle--gold,
.circle--purple,
.circle--teal {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden
}

@media (min-width:48em) {
  .circle--gold, .circle--purple, .circle--teal {
    display: block;
    visibility: visible
  }
}

.circle--purple {
  height: 430px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 430px;
  z-index: -1;
  background: #a177ff;
  background: linear-gradient(to top right, #a177ff 0, #FF6D92 100%);
  left: -275px
}

.circle--gold {
  height: 450px;
  width: 450px;
  z-index: -1;
  background: #FC636B;
  background: linear-gradient(to top right, #FC636B 0, #FF6D92 60%, #ffb900 100%);
  bottom: -125px;
  right: -200px
}

@media (min-width:70em) {
  .circle--purple {
    left: -200px
  }
  .circle--gold {
    bottom: -100px;
    right: 0
  }
}

.circle--teal {
  height: 430px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 430px;
  background: #a177ff;
  background: linear-gradient(to top right, #a177ff 0, #02CEFF 100%);
  right: -300px;
  z-index: -2
}
```

Any ideas about what I could be doing wrong, or what I could change to make this work?

Comment: I played around with your code in jsfiddle and you can check the result [here](https://jsfiddle.net/f0468f1s/2/). I also added some inline comments so you can understand what I did.

Comment: @ZiggyVerstrepen That worked great, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following code.

```
<body>
        <div class="demo">
      <div id="content">
        <h1>Heading</h1>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>

        <p>At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
      </div>


    <div class="footer">
      <p>This is a footer</p>
    </div>

    <div class="circle--purple"></div>
    <div class="circle--gold"></div>
    <div class="circle--teal"></div>
    </div>

html {
  height: 150%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after { box-sizing: inherit; }

body { 
  background: #f2f2f2;
  position: relative;
  /* NOTE: Disabing "position: relative" allows the
           circles to stay at the bottom of the window, 
           but not the bottom of the viewport. 
  */
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
}
.demo{
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;}
/**
 * Footer Styles
 */
.footer {
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
}

#content{
    padding-bottom:100px;}
/**
 * Circle Styles
 */
.circle--gold,
.circle--purple,
.circle--teal {
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 150ms
}

.circle--gold,
.circle--purple,
.circle--teal {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden
}

@media (min-width:48em) {
  .circle--gold, .circle--purple, .circle--teal {
    display: block;
    visibility: visible
  }
}

.circle--purple {
  height: 430px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 430px;
  z-index: -1;
  background: #a177ff;
  background: linear-gradient(to top right, #a177ff 0, #FF6D92 100%);
  left: -275px
}

.circle--gold {
  height: 450px;
  width: 450px;
  z-index: -1;
  background: #FC636B;
  background: linear-gradient(to top right, #FC636B 0, #FF6D92 60%, #ffb900 100%);
  bottom: -125px;
  right: -200px
}

@media (min-width:70em) {
  .circle--purple {
    left: -200px
  }
  .circle--gold {
    bottom: -100px;
    right: 0
  }
}

.circle--teal {
  height: 430px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 430px;
  background: #a177ff;
  background: linear-gradient(to top right, #a177ff 0, #02CEFF 100%);
  right: -300px;
  z-index: -2
}
```